# Definition of class constants in python

Tags: python

I'm newbie in python and I wonder if I can do something like this for definition of class constant: Tks

```
class MyClass:

    @classmethod
    @property
    def MY_CONSTANT(cls):
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work.

This is the typical pattern for class constants:

```
class MyClass:
    MY_CONSTANT = 0
```

A lot of things in Python (like read-only attributes) are done by convention in Python.

Comment: Explaining the OP why it won't work would be a welcome addition to your answer ;-)